# RC integral and differential functions, Schmitt triggers. How does this circuit work?

Tags: sensor, differential, schmitt-trigger, integrator

I'd be happy if someone explained me why this circuit is the way it is; how does it work ? Also i would like to know what the value for C1 is.

[image]

Taken from https://www.electroninvest.com/shop/items/sensors/801sshocksensorspecpdf.pdf

Comment: C1 is any value between 3.3 nF and 100 nF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit is a pulse frequency discriminator.  As already noted, both gates are inverters.

Whatever the sensor is, it's output must be some kind of square wave or pulse pattern.  C1, R2, and the left gate turns each positive transition into a constant width negative pulse.

RV and C2 turn this stream of constant width pulses into a DC level that varies with the off-times between pulses; the longer the gap between pulses, the more positive the voltage across C2.

The right gate compares this voltage to an internal reference and generates an output level based on the value of its input voltage.  As the input pulses get closer and closer together, the DC voltage on C2 gets lower and lower.  When the pulses are close enough together, the voltage on C2 is below the detection level of the right gate, and output voltage goes high.

One application for this kind of circuit is a fan fail detector.  Many fans have an optional tachometer pulse output which is an open collector transistor.  With this circuit, the output is high when the fan is running at normal speed, and goes low when the fan speed drops below some cutoff value.

Comment: Wait a minute - I don't get the 4th paragraph. The right gate is also a Schmitt trigger NAND gate. By `internal reference` do you mean the lower threshold voltage of the hysteresis loop ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.  The negative-going transition level is approx. 1/3Vdd.  The nice thing about the hysteretic inputs is that the signal crossing the transition level can be changing very slowly and you still will not get a noise burst at the output.

Comment: I am planning on using this as a vibration detector. Any idea whether the `Output must become square wave. (Can not use as shock switch!)` in the datasheet would prevent me from doing so ?

Answer (score 1):

- R1 is a pull-up resistor. Normally the left side of C1 will be at 9 V.
- When the sensor is triggered it will pull C1 low.
- The right side of C1 will try to go negative but will be clamped at about -0.7 V due to the internal parasitic diode of the 4093 gate.
- When the sensor opens C1 will be pulled high by R1. This will pull the 4093 input high for a time given by \$ \tau = R_2 C_1 \$. Note that the 4093 is an *inverting* gate. The schematic should show this.
- The output of the 4093 will charge up C2 at a rate given by \$ \tau = R_V C_2 \$. When it goes high enough the second gate will switch.
- When the first gate changes state the second gate will follow some time later.

The circuit is not very good and I think it will not give consistent output pulse width for input triggers.

---

> I have problems understanding these pullup / charging times. Why do you equate such times to precisely one time constant of the RC network?

The gates are inverting Schmitt triggers. When input > 2/3 x Vcc (approx. - see the datasheet) the output will pull low. When input < 1/3 Vcc the output will switch high. The RC time constant is the time taken to get 63% of the way from the starting voltage to the "infinite time" final voltage. The RC time constant will give you a pretty good approximation of the time.

> AFAI understand when the sensor opens C1 will be pulled up as long as the sensor stays open. Am I misunderstanding?

I couldn't really figure out which way the sensor is: normally open or closed. Hence the vagueness in my answer. I did start to read the Instructables article but it was too long. AnalogKid may be right about the integrator staying on longer as the pulse frequency increases.

---

> I understand the approximations, what I was asking, at least for the first gate, was why take the time constant instead of, I would think, MIN(τ, T), where T = the time the sensor stays open (assuming it is a normally open).

I'm not sure that I understand your confusion but a simulation might help.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyLj7q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. CircuitLab simulation of circuit. CircuitLab gates switch at 2 and 3 V and that will be good enough for a Schmitt trigger simulation. They don't seem to include the parasitic diodes so these are shown externally.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Simulation with 1 Hz trigger signal. Output pulse is high for 10% of the time.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Simulation with 5 Hz trigger signal. (Note different time scale.) Output pulse is high for 50% of the time.

I haven't included a trace of the output of NOT1 but if you add it yourself you should see that it is a constant width, independent of input frequency (up to a point). Effectively it's an edge-triggered one-shot.

You should be able to play with the simulation yourself. Copy my circuit into a new question or answer and paste it in. Run a time domain simulation with settings as shown below (for starters).

[image]

*Figure 4. Simulator settings.*

Comment: Hmm, okay. I have problems understanding these pullup / charging times. Why do you equate such times to precisely one time constant of the RC network ? AFAI understand when the sensor opens C1 will be pulled up as long as the sensor stays open. Am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I understand the approximations, what I was asking, say for the first gate, was why take the time constant as a measure of how long C1 gets pulled up for instead of T = the time the sensor stays open (assuming it is normally open) ? I think τ would be the approximate width of the impulse on the other side of the gate - at its output. Or ?

Comment: See the update.